# How to fix extra buttons on a Wordpress Video playlist

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, wai-aria

I have recently begun assisting updating my company's website.  We have a few video playlists that I noticed have a *ton* of extra navigation buttons.  I have an attached screenshot with the navigation circled.

I cannot figure out where the extra buttons are coming from, so I am unfortunately not even sure what the best questions are to ask here.  The best I can find from digging around in the CSS are that there are references to mejs and aria. For all of my toying around. I have not been able to isolate one set of the buttons to go away and still show standard navigation buttons.

[image: Video Playlist with extra Navigation buttons]

Thank you!

Comment: Right now, you don't have a programming question so I'm voting to close as off-topic... If everything is allright and the player is not mangled (looks very weird), you should be able to detect where it's coming from and what assets are being used via the browser console. See [Edit the DOM  |  Tools for Web Developers  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom)

Comment: I have been testing hiding nearly every element with the browser console already, to no avail.  If there is a better place I can ask this question to someone who might have more experience with mejs or aria, can you point me in that direction please?

Comment: Check past questions tagged with [tag:medialement.js] and [tag:wai-aria], they'll probably have clues of what code/keywords you should be looking for

Comment: I will do that.  Thank you.

Comment: ARIA tags have absolutely nothing to do with the display.  They are for adding semantic information to the page so that screen readers understand what is being conveyed.  That should help narrow down your debugging focus.  You can ignore trying to track down what ARIA tags might be causing the problem because unless you are using a screen reader, you will never know they're there.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious.

Comment: At this point, I've narrowed it down to this line of CSS:
.mejs-controls .mejs-button button{cursor:pointer;display:block;font-size:0;line-height:0;text-decoration:none;margin:7px 5px;padding:0;position:absolute;height:16px;width:16px;border:0;background:transparent url(controls.svg) no-repeat}  
  
My best guess is that the controls.svg should only be displaying one character, but it's displaying the entire image instead.  I'm still trying to figure out how to test that theory, and if I'm right, what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check CSS Styling for input[type='button'] or button in your CSS.